# External reference in JSON validation with Everit yields "FileNotFoundException"

Tags: java, json, json-schema-validator, everit

I'm attempting to add JSON schema validation to sanitize user inputs for a Java application. All of the schema are stored in the file system that's doing the validation. My schema is something like this:

```
{
  "$id": "https://www.my-url.org/schemas/schemaName.json",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "Train Approximation",
  "type": "object",
  "properties":{
    "settings":{
      "type":"object",
      "oneOf":[
        {"$ref":"https://www.my-url.org/anotherSchema.json"}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

(There's additional items in the "oneOf", plus other properties and descriptions that aren't relevant.)

I'm using the Everit library for schema validation. My code for checking schema looks like this:

```
String[] schemaNames = {"schemaName.json","anotherSchema.json", "moreSchemasEtc.json"};

String schemaFile = schemaName + ".json";
File fSchemaFile = new File(dir.getAbsoluteFile() + File.separator + schemaFile);
if (fSchemaFile.exists()) {
  try (InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fSchemaFile)) {
    JSONObject rawSchema = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(inputStream));
                        
    SchemaLoaderBuilder slb = SchemaLoader.builder()
      .schemaClient(SchemaClient.classPathAwareClient())
      .schemaJson(rawSchema)
      .resolutionScope("classpath://Schema");
                        
    for(String schemaFileName : schemaNames) {
      File tSchemaFile = new File(dir.getAbsoluteFile() + File.separator + schemaFileName);
      InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(tSchemaFile);
      JSONObject rawTSchema = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(inStream));
      slb.registerSchemaByURI(new URI("https://www.my-url.org/schemas/"+schemaFileName), rawTSchema);
    }
                        
    SchemaLoader schemaLoader = slb.build();
                        
    Schema schema = schemaLoader.load().build();
    schema.validate(new JSONObject(jsonString));

  } catch (ValidationException e) {
    //Do error handling
  }
} else { /* Do other stuff */ }
```

This works for all of my schema that don't have external references. (E.g: `"$ref":"https://www.my-url.org/anotherSchema.json"`) For schema like the one I have posted here, I get a `java.io.FileNotFoundException` with the path from the reference.

What am I doing wrong here? I also tried:
-Using the classpath aware client (still in the code above) and adding the parent directory above my `/Schema/` directory to my Java classpath, then referencing everything as e.g `"$ref":"anotherSchema.json"` instead of having the whole path
-Using the `my-url.org` path in the resolution scope instead of classpath

With the classpath option, I get an error that has a path like `classpath://Schema/anotherSchema.json` in the FileNotFoundException, but an exception nonetheless.